# How to prevent google fonts <link> code triggering clicks in Pardot?

Tags: html, css, email

I am working in Pardot and we include the following line of code in our  section to pull in the Open Sans custom font:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;700&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

This is working for the font but I have an issue where this link is triggering a click in lots of people's emails and causing our CTR to be inflated, do you know why this is happening?

Thank you,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Pardot tracks anything in a `<link>` as a link click so just use the @import method:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap');
</style>
```